# Connecting PC to chromecast

Tags: desktop-computer, chromecast

I have a PC connected to a router with wire and a chromecast device connected to the wifi of the same router. Is it possible to connect these 2 device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

When the PC is connected to the same wifi, the browser Chrome will be able to find the chromecast. From there you can either cast webpages or services, such as youtube, or the entire desktop.

Do note, you do need a Chromium based browser to stream your desktop to a chromecast. I use Vivaldi, another chromium based browser myself.